# How effective were arrow-firing guns?

Tags: weapons, asia, korea

In the Europe, briefly after the appearance of firearm, gun-fired arrows made their appearance, but very soon after, the ball projectiles became standard ammunition used in both cannons and handgonnes and gun-fired arrows disappeared.

As for the Asia, the gun-fired arrows sticked for longer. For example [History of Korean cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_cannon#Early_Mid_Joseon_(mid_15th_century_to_mid_16th_century)) mentions cannons firing darts/arrows in 17th century. What advantages does firing an arrow from cannon/gun has over firing a ball? In other words, why would they use it?

[While I am also interested in arrow-rockets, I am not asking about those in this question. What I am asking about is an arrow/dart put inside a firearm/cannon, and fired from it. I welcome any self-study resource recommendation.]

Comment: "gun-fired arrows disappeared" but they have recently [made a comeback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armour-piercing_fin-stabilized_discarding_sabot).

Comment: I imagine piercing power is greater, worth investigating that.

Comment: As a guess, *direct-fire* mechanical scorpions used arrows, *indirect-fire* trebuchets used rocks. They were building new *direct-fire* weapons and tried arrows.